# What would be the prize value in today's terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a $1 million dollar competitions came out roughly in 1985. Would would the equivalent prize money be today?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have information about the inflation rate to use? Otherwise, this problem is pretty much unsolvable.

Comment: Seems to me you just 'want the answer'. In that case you might as well use http://146.142.4.24/cgi-bin/cpicalc.pl or similar results on google.

Comment: In what country?

Comment: I think he just wants some estimate for inflation. Basically probably what he is looking for is $\$1,000,000 \times (1.05)^{27}=\$3,700,000$ approximately.

Comment: Try http://measuringworth.com/, e.g., http://www.measuringworth.com/uscompare/relativevalue.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Current Value of Old Money](http://projects.exeter.ac.uk/RDavies/arian/current/howmuch.html) is a useful site for this purpose.

The answer specifically to this question is [approximately $2 million (depending on how you calculate it).](http://www.measuringworth.com/uscompare/result.php?year_source=1985&amount=1000000&year_result=2011)

USA's CPI calculation is probably most relevant to you - as this measures inflation (in the US) according to the value of typical household purchases. (So, to be more precise, you might consider a different CPI that reflects relevant luxury purchases) Anyway, \$2.09 million is a sensible value to choose from this table. Note that it's 2012, so you might consider adding ~2.4% for this year's CPI, giving you **\$2.14 million**.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just wanted a rough idea of what that value might be in today's terms.